# open 2013 microsoft word document vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am unable to open a Microsoft Word document in vb.net. I have the following imports:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office
Imports Microsoft.Office.Core
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
```

When I try to call Word in my code I get the following error:

Type 'Word.Application' is not defined

```
Dim appWord As New Word.Application
Dim docWord As New Word.Document
```

Do I need to download a library or something else?

Comment: As long as you have Microsoft Word Object Library (COM reference) added to your project references, this should work fine. I don't have any issues doing the same thing.

Comment: I have added the (COM reference) and it works fine now. Thank you!

Comment: Usually, you need to have Microsoft Office or at least Word installed on the PC that you're developing on and the machine that you will install the software on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the Microsoft Word Object Library (found under Project Settings -> References -> Add New Reference, then selecting the COM reference tab).

Doing this, in addition to your current `Imports` statements, should take care of it.

Note that after adding the reference, while still in your references page of your project properties, you can scroll through the imported namespaces list and check the checkbox next to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` and not have to add the `Imports` statements (although it's still a good idea to use them, for readability).

Also, as Paul mentioned in the comments above, you will need Word installed on the machine you are developing on and on any machine running your program (can't open Word if it isn't there!).

[How to automate Word from Visual Basic .NET to create a new document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316383)

Answer (score 2):

If you have

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
```

but not

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
```

it will report Word.Application as not defined.

So either change the import to

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
```

Or change the instantiator to

```
Dim appWord as New Application
```

Comment: This is now working when I debug, but when Published to the test environment I get an ActiveX error.

Cannot create ActiveX component.

Comment: Does your test environment have all your components installed? Did it work ever, or work up until a recent change? Any chance to identify the specific code triggering the activex error?

Comment: This is the first test. The server does not have word. I may try to automate word to open the file. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: If the intention is to process Word documents on the server, it would be best to get it installed asap.